# How to load Partial View inside Button Popover?

Tags: .net-core, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to display a partial view inside a button popover.

cshtml:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body"
    data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" id="popoverBtn"
    data-content="@(await Html.PartialAsync("_ListBoxPartial"))">
Popover on bottom
```

Partial View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <select name="test" style="width:100%;" id="selectMultiple" class="form-control custom-select" multiple>
            <option>123</option>
            <option>456</option>
            <option>789</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it displays like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `RenderPartialAsync`, use `PartialAsync`

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" 
    data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" id="popoverBtn" 
    data-content="@(await Html.PartialAsync("_ListBoxPartial"))">
    Popover on bottom
</button>
```

If you are initializing your popover via javascript, [the v4 documentation of bootrap states](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#options):

> `html` (boolean property with a default of `false`): Insert HTML into
> the popover. If false, jQuery's text method will be used to insert
> content into the DOM. Use text if you're worried about XSS attacks.

I haven't tried it but there might also be a data attribute equivalent of `data-html="true"` if you are not using js to initialize the popover (it would seem odd if there is though).

Comment: Tried this, this is the output https://imgur.com/a/w85B2t8

Comment: @TerribleDog: Can you repost your updated code please?

Comment: updated it. Please see the question

Comment: I don't see any reason it shouldn't work. Provided you are using `@(` instead of `@{` and you have a closing tag for your `<\button>`

Comment: Just added a comment about the `html` option for popovers.

Comment: @TerribleDog - any luck with  the `html` option?